# Блоки CSS разметка картинки

Tags: css, разметка, блок

Немного не понимаю как работают блоки в CSS, и вот когда пытался сделать очередной простенький сайт для тренеровки столкнулся с этой проблемой, дело в том что у меня есть слева небольшой блок, а так же картинка(снизу) Я прописал картинке float right она становится левее но не встает рядом с блоком справа как это исправить? [image: введите сюда описание изображения] ( нужно что бы картинка была на уровне с голубым блоком )

Answer (score 0):

Голубому блоку поставьте `float: left`. А еще лучше прикрепите код.